# Simple UnityContainerExtension

Tags: unity-container

I'm working on an application that is using the bbv EventBrokerExtension library. What I'm trying to accomplish is that I want to have unity register the instance that are instantiated through the container with the EventBroker. I'm planning on doing this through a UnityContainerExtension and implementing the IBuilderStrategy. The problem is that the methods for the interface seem to be called for each parameter in the constructor. The problem is when Singleton instances get resolved when building an object they will be registered multiple times.

For instance suppose you had

```
class Foo(ISingletonInterface singleton){}
class Foo2(ISingletonInterface singleton){}
```

and you resolve them via unity using

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.AddNewExtension<EventBrokerWireupStrategy>();
container.RegisterInstance<IEventBroker>(new EventBroker());
container.RegisterInstance(new Singleton());
var foo = container.Resolve<Foo>();
var foo2 = container.Resolve<Foo2>();
```

Then the UnityContainerExtension will call postbuildup on the same singleton object. Here is my naive implementation of UnityContainerExtension.

```
using Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder;
using bbv.Common.EventBroker;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace PFC.EventingModel.EventBrokerExtension
{
public class EventBrokerWireupExtension : UnityContainerExtension, IBuilderStrategy
{
    private IEventBroker _eventBroker;
    private List<object> _wiredObjects = new List<object>();

    public EventBrokerWireupExtension(IEventBroker eventBroker)
    {
        _eventBroker = eventBroker;
    }


    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Context.Strategies.Add(this, UnityBuildStage.PostInitialization);
    }

    public void PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
    {

    }

    public void PostBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
    {
        if (!_wiredObjects.Contains(context.Existing))
        {
            _eventBroker.Register(context.Existing);
            _wiredObjects.Add(context.Existing);
        }
    }

    public void PreTearDown(IBuilderContext context)
    {

    }

    public void PostTearDown(IBuilderContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation it appears that the problem has to do with the EventBrokerExtension. If I subscribe them in a certain order then some of them don't get registered with the event broker.

UPDATE:

Wanted to update this question really quick with the answer in case anyone else witnesses similar behavior when using the bbv EventBroker library. The behavior I was seeing was that a subscriber would get events for a while but then would stop receiving events. By design the EventBroker only maintains weak references to the publishers and subscribers that have been registered. Since the eventbroker was the only class referencing the objects they were getting garbage collected at an indeterminate time and wouldn't receive events anymore. The solution was simply to create a hard reference somewhere in the application besides the EventBroker.